# How do I add code to my viewcontroller.swift for views connected via a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I am pretty new to Xcode (but not programming in general, have learned a bit of python and java) and I am trying to figure out, for the life of me, how I connect bits of code in other views besides the first one when they are linked from a navigation controller.

To paint a picture of this, I essentially start out with a single view application, I have the first view and I add a button to it and then I embed it in a navigation controller by doing.. Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller. The next time, as I have been following from various guides online, is that I control drag that button to that view and hit "show" to link them. Now say I have another button in that new view I just linked to. Xcode doesn't seem to let me just control drag that button onto the text in viewcontroller.swift, I believe that this is because they are two separate view controllers now however I have not a clue where the second viewcontroller2.swift file may be. Or, maybe, there is an easier way to link the two views together and actually be able to modify the source files?

Comment: You are trying to link two view controllers, right?

Comment: If it's possible to avoid such a thing, then no. Really, I am just trying to link two views together but I don't know how to control drag buttons or labels from the second view to the code that is readily mutable in viewcontroller.swift

Comment: So you have two `UIView` on your `UIViewController` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find a "ViewController2" you won't find it, because you have to create it!  Use Command-N to create a new file and choose "Cocoa Touch Class".  Name it something like SecondViewController and make sure it's a subclass of UIViewController.  Now you can go back to interface builder and change the class of the second view controller to whatever name you just chose, like SecondViewController.

To address the other part of your question (I think), I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.  If you want some of your data to transfer to the new ViewController, use the prepareForSegue function in the first ViewController.

Comment: Using this method, how do i link SecondViewController.swift to the second view in storyboard?

Comment: @VladPapov Click on the ViewController in your storyboard, then go to the identity inspector tab of the sidebar on the right.  It's the tab with the icon that kind of looks like an ID.  There's a class field in that tab.